# Add column to order grid get error in customer page

Tags: magento2, sales-order, magento2.2.4, custom-column-grid

I tried to add 2 new columns (shipping's company and billing's company) to orders page using a plugin,
but i got an error when trying to view customer's orders in customer page.
[image]
This is my plugin function

```
public function afterGetReport($subject, $collection, $requestName)
{
    if ($requestName !== 'sales_order_grid_data_source') {
        return $collection;
    }

    if ($collection->getMainTable() === $collection->getResource()->getTable('sales_order_grid')) {
        try {
            $orderAddressTableName           = $collection->getResource()->getTable('sales_order_address');
            //$directoryCountryRegionTableName = $collection->getResource()->getTable('directory_country_region');
            $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
                ['soat' => $orderAddressTableName],
                'soat.parent_id = main_table.entity_id AND soat.address_type = \'shipping\'' ,
                 [
                    'company_shipp' => 'company'
                ]
            );
            $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
                ['soat1' => $orderAddressTableName],
                'soat1.parent_id = main_table.entity_id AND soat1.address_type = \'billing\'',
                 [
                    'company_bill' => 'company'
                ]
            )->where();

         } catch (\Zend_Db_Select_Exception $selectException) {
            // Do nothing in that case
            $this->logger->log(100, $selectException);
         }
     }

     return $collection;
 }
```

My be my code is wrong to get both billing and shpping company in 2 custom columns,
But i got error 
This is the error Column 'customer_id' in where clause is ambiguous, can i override the where in my function but how to get the customer?

> Exception #0 (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity    constraint violation: 1052 Column 'customer_id' in where clause is ambiguous,    query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `sales_order_grid` AS `main_table`
>       LEFT JOIN `ggg_flags_order_flag` AS `amflags_column_1` ON    main_table.entity_id = amflags_column_1.order_id AND   amflags_column_1.column_id = 1
>       LEFT JOIN `ggg_flags_order_flag` AS `amflags_column_2` ON main_table.entity_id = amflags_column_2.order_id AND amflags_column_2.column_id = 2
>       LEFT JOIN `ggg_flags_order_flag` AS `amflags_column_3` ON  main_table.entity_id = amflags_column_3.order_id AND   amflags_column_3.column_id = 3
>       LEFT JOIN `ggg_flags_order_flag` AS `amflags_column_4` ON main_table.entity_id = amflags_column_4.order_id AND amflags_column_4.column_id = 4
>       LEFT JOIN `ggg_flags_order_flag` AS `amflags_column_5` ON main_table.entity_id = amflags_column_5.order_id AND amflags_column_5.column_id = 5
>       LEFT JOIN `ggg_flags_order_flag` AS `amflags_column_6` ON main_table.entity_id = amflags_column_6.order_id AND amflags_column_6.column_id = 6
>       LEFT JOIN `ggg_flags_order_flag` AS `amflags_column_7` ON main_table.entity_id = amflags_column_7.order_id AND amflags_column_7.column_id = 7
>      LEFT JOIN `ggg_flags_order_flag` AS `amflags_column_8` ON main_table.entity_id = amflags_column_8.order_id AND amflags_column_8.column_id = 8
>       LEFT JOIN `ggg_flags_order_flag` AS `amflags_column_9` ON main_table.entity_id = amflags_column_9.order_id AND amflags_column_9.column_id = 9
>       LEFT JOIN `ggg_flags_order_flag` AS `amflags_column_10` ON main_table.entity_id = amflags_column_10.order_id AND amflags_column_10.column_id = 10
>       LEFT JOIN `ggg_flags_order_flag` AS `amflags_column_11` ON main_table.entity_id = amflags_column_11.order_id AND amflags_column_11.column_id = 11
>    LEFT JOIN `sales_order_address` AS `soat` ON soat.parent_id = main_table.entity_id 
>       LEFT JOIN `sales_order_address` AS `soat1` ON soat1.parent_id = main_table.entity_id  WHERE (soat.address_type = 'shipping') AND (soat1.address_type = 'billing') AND (`**customer_id**` = '11617')

Answer (score 2):

Overwrite following class:

```
Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection
```

After that add following method into your class:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
protected function _construct()
{
    parent::_construct();
    $this->addFilterToMap(
        'customer_id',
        'main_table.customer_id'
    );
}
```

***Note: this is not tested code, but that way should work.***

Comment: I used $colletion->addFilterToMap(
        'customer_id',
        'main_table.customer_id'
    ); without overriding and it works. Thanks for the code

Answer (score 1):

With code given by @Sohel, i changed field prefix without overriding any class, it contains code to fix filtering issue for the new columns

```
public function afterGetReport($subject, $collection, $requestName)
{
    if ($requestName !== 'sales_order_grid_data_source') {
        return $collection;
    }

    if ($collection->getMainTable() === $collection->getResource()->getTable('sales_order_grid')) {
        try {
            $orderAddressTableName           = $collection->getResource()->getTable('sales_order_address');
            //$directoryCountryRegionTableName = $collection->getResource()->getTable('directory_country_region');

            $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
                ['soat' => $orderAddressTableName],
                'soat.parent_id = main_table.entity_id AND( soat.address_type = \'shipping\')' ,
                 [
                    'company_shipp' => 'company'
                ]
            );
            $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
                ['soat1' => $orderAddressTableName],
                'soat1.parent_id = main_table.entity_id AND soat1.address_type = \'billing\'',
                 [
                    'company_bill' => 'company'
                ]
            );
            $collection
                ->addFilterToMap(
                'company_bill',
                        'soat1.company'

            );
            $collection
                ->addFilterToMap(
                'company_shipp',
                        'soat.company'

            );
            $collection->addFilterToMap(
                'customer_id',
                'main_table.customer_id'
            );

        } catch (\Zend_Db_Select_Exception $selectException) {
            // Do nothing in that case
            var_dump($collection);
            $this->logger->log(100, $selectException);
        }
    }

    return $collection;
}
```